# Loading head of sas7bdat table to Python or R

Tags: python, r, sas

I have a exported tables from SAS in format sas7bdat and I have no SAS. These tables need to be checked that contain expected varibales and datatypes. To be able to do it, I need to load only fraction of these dataframes into R or Python.

For the smaller tables, I use

```
client_ft_lremm = pandas.read_sas("C:/Users/USER/Documents/client_ft_lremm.sas7bdat").head(10)
```

But it still loads the whole frame and then select top 10.

Reason for this is size of some of the tables(more then 17GB) exceeding my RAM, so it overloads and drops.

Is there a possibility to load top 10 rows of SAS7BDAT table without loading the whole tables to RAM?

Thank you

Comment: `haven::read_sas` would be the common way to read these files into R, and you can read in separate columns at a time (but not rows) to possibly reduce memory usage.

Comment: If you have the `RevoScaleR` package in `R`, the `rxImport` would be a good option.  There are argument to select rows/columns etc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/r-server/r-reference/revoscaler/rximport)

Comment: `chunksize=` and `iterator=True` maybe?

Comment: @Axeman, Thanks, but this would increase time.

Comment: @akrun This is nice way of doing it. I moved the whole process to the R SERVER where is 128GB ram. So I'm able to load everything and do the some basic analysis. Thank you akrun

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SAS Universal Viewer (https://support.sas.com/downloads/package.htm?pid=712).  This is a Windows application that lets you view SAS Data Sets.  You will have to manually inspect them, but it should do what you need.

Comment: Thank, it sounds as a nice workaround, but I'm aiming for R or Pyhton.